# Программа в Паскаль - Обработка строк

Tags: массивы, алгоритм, строки, pascal

Напишите программу, реализующего обработку строк. Даны строки S и S0.Удалить из строки S первую подстроку, совпадающую с S0.Если совпадающих нет то без изменений S.Язык програмированния - Pascal.
Пытаюсь создать программу обработки строк, не судите строго я плохо что понимаю, в ответе видно, ну вряд ли правильно, сыровато...
Моя попытка...

```
cnt :=0;
for i :=1 to N - s do
for j :=i + s to N do
if a[i]*a[j] mod 13 = 0 then
cnt :=cnt +1;
writeln(cnt)
```

Comment: **Учебные задания допустимы в качестве вопросов только при условии, что вы пытались решить их самостоятельно перед тем, как задать вопрос**. Пожалуйста, отредактируйте ([edit]) вопрос и **укажите, что именно вызвало у вас трудности** при решении задачи. Например, приведите код, который вы написали, пытаясь решить задачу.

Comment: А ... вы какие-нибудь встроенные функции, связанные со строками, видели? [Посмотрите](https://kvodo.ru/procedury-i-funkcii-dlya-raboty-so-strokami-paskal.html?utm_referrer=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2F)

Answer (score 1):

Например можно таким образом:

**Вариант 1**
Формируем новую строку, объединив части S, которые находятся перед и после найденного вхождения S0

```
var
  S, S0, Response: string;
  Idx: Integer;

begin
  Write('S = ');
  Readln(S);
  Writeln;
  Write('S0 = ');
  Readln(S0);

  // Находим первое вхождения подстроки S0 в строке S
  Idx := Pos(S0, S);

  // Если вхождение найдено, то удаляем его и формируем новую строку 
  if Index > 0 then
  begin
    Response := Copy(S, 1, Index - 1) + Copy(S, Index + Length(S0), Length(S) - Index - Length(S0) + 1);
    Writeln('Response: ', Response);
  end
  else
  begin
    Writeln('Подстрока не найдена');
  end;

  Readln;
end.
```

**Вариант 2** Удаление его с помощью процедуры Delete

```
var
  S, S0: string;
  Idx: Integer;

begin
  // Ввод исходной строки S и подстроки S0
  Write('S = ');
  Readln(S);
  Writeln;
  Write('S) = ');
  Readln(S0);

  Index := Pos(S0, S);

  // Если вхождение найдено, то удаляем его и выводим результат
  if Index > 0 then
  begin
    Delete(S, Index, Length(S0));
    Writeln('Результат: ', S);
  end
  else
  begin
    Writeln('Подстрока не найдена');
  end;

  Readln;
end.
```

Comment: Если исходную строку не нужно сохранять, то проще Delete вместо набора Copy. А насчёт Copy конца строки ещё полезное - можно не считать количество символов, а дать с запасом - скопируется имеющийся хвост без ошибки.

Comment: @MBo Учту, сейчас дополню ответ. про `можно не считать количество символов, а дать с запасом -` не совсем понял

Comment: Вместо к-ства поставить к примеру 255, или какой там размер стринга в паскаль.

Comment: Да просто Length(s) можно ставить третьим параметром вместо `Length(S) - Index - Length(S0) + 1`

Comment: @MBo Мне кажется это полезно только для оптимизации, а не для чтения кода. Ибо факт того, что паскаль не выдает ошибку в таком случае, а работает исправно - не очевиден. так же учитывая, что автор, скорее всего только учится, то думаю что такой вариант не пойдет ему на пользу

Comment: Ну это не особенная оптимизация, просто небольшое удобство, чтобы скопировать весь конец.

Comment: переменная `Index` нигде не объявлена